# Maven is installing a dependency to the local repository that is not in the dependency tree or my POM

Tags: java, maven

I have a dependency getting installed that I'm trying to get rid of, but I can't tell what is causing it to be installed.  If I do a `find`, it shows up in the local repository.  And in my build server logs, there's a "Downloading https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xxxxxxx" entry for it.

But I don't have the dependency included in my `pom.xml` file, and it doesn't show up when I do `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` or `mvn help:effective-pom`.  How can I further debug where this is coming from?  Thanks.

Comment: You have not correctly defined your correct settings.xml file to use a repository manager which prevents such things. Apart from that finding this dependency it should be logged into the build log output of the build server.

Comment: I'm just using the default settings file that comes with Maven.  That seems odd that I'd need to customize the installation to avoid phantom dependencies from being installed.  Also, I am seeing it in the build log output, but that unfortunately doesn't get me any closer to figuring out what's causing it to be installed.